# css transitions: hover out transition not working if hover in is not allowed to complete

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a `div`, for which `css transitions` are applied on `hover`, 
on `hover in`, a `transition` is applied on the `:before element`, and on `hover out`, same `transition` (reversed) is applied on the `:before` element.

here is the html:

```
<section class="strips">
          <article class="strips__strip">
                <div class="strip__content">
                  <h1 class="strip__title">Title</h1>
                </div>
          </article>
</section>
```

and (important parts of) the css:

```
.strips .strip__content:hover:before {
  transform: skew(180deg) scale(1) translate(0, 0);
  opacity: 0.1;
}

.strips .strip__content:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.05;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: skew(180deg) scaleY(0) translate(0, 0);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
```

Now, the transitions work smoothly if i allow tem to finish, but say, if i dont allow the hover in transition to finish , and quickly hover out, then the hover out transition does not work.

here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/x2pavnac/

(try hovering out before the transition finishes).

I am not sure why this happens and how this issue can be addressed in css.

EDIT:

i have simplified the transition and also increased opacity, so it is more visible.
Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x2pavnac/4/

Comment: Its working fine for me?

Comment: did you try moving your mouse out of the div before the hover in completes?

Comment: Yup. It slides open, then slides back to closed if I move out quickly - no matter at which point I do it. Is this not the desired effect?

Comment: @GavinThomas Yes, it is the desired effect. but, it does not slide close for me in the same scenario. i am using chrome.

Comment: Fx 45 here, your latest fiddle is working fine: when I interrupt the animation, it will reverse nicely and slide shut again. Latest Cr does indeed show problematic behaviour: the hover-in will first complete, but it will be shown as a completed hovered-in animation while the time it would have taken the hover-in to complete, and only after that time will Cr transition the state of the element to hovered-out.

Comment: I am seeing the problematic behavior in Chrome as well.  I would call this a chrome bug.  I think you could work around it with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this works well for others, but i found a typo in my css which was the issue in my case:

```
.strips .strip__content:before {
  transform: skew(180deg) scaleY(0) translate(0, 0);
}

.strips .strip__content:hover:before {
  transform: skew(180deg) scale(1) translate(0, 0);
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

should be

```
.strips .strip__content:before {
  transform: skew(180deg) scaleY(0) translate(0, 0);
}

.strips .strip__content:hover:before {
  transform: skew(180deg) scaleY(1) translate(0, 0);
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

notice the scaleY(1) instead of scale(1).

I am still not sure why it worked correctly for others though, even with the typo.